# Развертка графика в pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyside2, pyqtgraph

Возможно ли производить развёртку графика в pyqtgraph с помощью колёсика мыши? Стандартно, колёсико мыши изменяет масштаб к точке. А нужно, чтобы масштаб по Y был постоянным и изменялся масштаб только по оси X. Если данное решение нельзя реализовать с помощью колёсика мыши, то как лучше всего это все сделать?